# tag 'Text_4' not seen in training corpus/invalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, gensim, doc2vec

I will need a little help with diagnosing some problem I am experiencing with some text vector process. Actually, I am  trying apply doc2vec word embedding to obtain a vector for a classification task. After I run the code I get some errors which has been quite difficult to figure out, as I am pretty new. Below are the codes and the outputs

```
    def constructLabeledSentences(data):
    sentences=[]
    for index, row in data.iteritems():
        sentences.append(TaggedDocument(utils.to_unicode(row).split(), ['Text' + '_%s' % str(index)]))
    return sentences

    x_raw_doc_sentences = constructLabeledSentences(x_raw_train['Text'])
x_raw_doc_model = Doc2Vec(min_count=5, window=5, vector_size=300, sample=0.001, negative=5, workers=4, epochs=10,seed=1)
x_raw_doc_model.build_vocab(x_raw_doc_sentences)
x_raw_doc_model.train(x_raw_doc_sentences, total_examples=x_raw_doc_model.corpus_count, epochs=x_raw_doc_model.epochs)
```

After running the model, I tried to extract the vectors with:

```
x_raw_doc_train_arrays = np.zeros((x_raw_train.shape[0], 300))
for i in range (x_raw_train.shape[0]):
    x_raw_doc_train_arrays[i]=x_raw_doc_model.docvecs['Text_'+str(i)]
```

and this is the output i get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-106-bc0222fef295> in <module>()
      1 x_raw_doc_train_arrays = np.zeros((x_raw_train.shape[0], 300))
      2 for i in range (x_raw_train.shape[0]):
----> 3     x_raw_doc_train_arrays[i]=x_raw_doc_model.docvecs['Text_'+str(i)]
      4 
      5 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py in __getitem__(self, index)
   1197                 return self.vectors_docs[self._int_index(index, self.doctags, self.max_rawint)]
   1198             return vstack([self[i] for i in index])
-> 1199         raise KeyError("tag '%s' not seen in training corpus/invalid" % index)
   1200 
   1201     def __contains__(self, index):

KeyError: "tag 'Text_4' not seen in training corpus/invalid"
```

Is there anything I did wrong, or should be doing that I haven't?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at `sentences` to be sure a `TaggedDocument` with a `tags` that includes `'Text_4'` is present?

And if so, is there anything peculiar about that document that might prevent it from contributing its tags? For example, is it empty of words, either initially, or after the `min_count` of words is applied and all rare-words are ignored (which is typically a good idea for vector quality)?

Note also that you can use raw integers as the individual tag values in `tags`. (And in that case, the `docvecs` array is initialized to contain vectors for all indexes up to the highest one you use – so a value like `4` that corresponds to a no-op example *would* get a vector, but it'd not have been adjusted at all during training, staying at its initialized random value.)

Comment: re-running the model once again made it work perfectly, thank you.